# How do I interpret an error message from DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to find non-trivial solutions of the ODE $\lambda u'(x) = u(x+R) - u(x)$ using *Mathematica*.

In particular, I am using the command

```
 DSolve[a*y'[x] == y[x + r] - y[x], y[x], x]
```

which for a standard (i.e., non-delayed, *non-anticipated* ODE) works fine.

In this case I got the error

> DSolve::litarg: "To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable    in !({a\\ *SuperscriptBox[\"y\", \"[Prime]\",
>   MultilineFunction->None][x] == (-y[x]) + y[r + x]}) should literally match the independent variables."

Any advice?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/DSolve/litarg.html) yet?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, sorry, thanks for the doc link. Indeed I googled the error; although I found general answers which I am too newbie o be able to uderstand. Be patient.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that doc page doesn't really help solve the DDE

Comment: I suggest you look at this [doc page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveDelayDifferentialEquations.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a delay differential equation, not an ODE. Mathematica can numerically solve DDEs with constant delays, eg, scaling `u` and `x` to reduce your DDE to $u'(x)=u(x+1)-u(x)$, we can do

```
sln = NDSolve[{u'[x] == u[x - 1] - u[x], 
       u[x /; x <= 0] == x^2}, u, {x, -1, 5}];
Plot[u[x] /. sln, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: No way to have some sort of general integral, I guess, right?

Comment: not that I know of

Comment: Thanks for the precious help, btw.